# data table detection in an image using descriptors?

Tags: opencv, detection, feature-descriptor

is there anyway to detect a statistical table in an image using descriptors? I have trained a haar classifier using opencv already. is there any other way or technique to detect whether there is a table in a given image ?

**Edit 1:** 
Find the hough line transfrom i did to the table below.
[image]

What are the conceptual ways to detect objects in an image?

Comment: Use [Hough Line Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html). Then find the aspect ratio of rectangles then if have a standard table you will find it. I think that works. If it is possible share your image!

Comment: i have tried that too. i will edit the question with an image of Hough line transform. what i need is conceptual techniques to detect something in an image. like LBP, Shape Contexts, Histogram of Oriented Gradients.